# iPhone / IOS No Audio Interruption Ended after playing video in Safari

Tags: iphone, video, mobile-safari, audio-recording

V4.x

We have an app that is recording audio in the background.  No problem.

1) Phone call comes in
2) App gets Audio Interruption Event
3) Phone Call ends
4) App gets Audio Interruption Ended Event
5) We popup a Local Notification to restart
6) User says ok
7) We come to front and start the recorder

But when someone plays a video in say Safari

1) User plays video in Safari
2) App gets Audio Interruption Event
3) Video Ends / User stops / ends Safari
4) NO Audio Interruption Event.

Anyone else has seen this?  Work around?  Some other event?

Comment: I bet it has something to do with the fact that your app is in the background when the user is using Safari. What happens when you bring the app to the foreground after Safari exits? Since you get the interrupt begin event, you might want to keep track of that, and when the app resumes, if it had been interrupted and hasn't received the interrupt end event, then restart. But I can see that you'd have a gap in your recording in this case. Hmm...

Comment: Well, with the phone interruption, even if in background, I get the end event.  When the user eventually brings the app to the foreground, yes then it can start itself several ways.  There is no End event ever.  Also, I do get the event even if in the background when a phone call comes on (or another recording app takes the recording).

Comment: For grins, what's the behavior if instead of using Safari and a video, use another app, like iTunes, and play some music. What is the behavior of your app then? I'm still thinking it has something to do with your app being in the background when the audio interruption ends. Being interrupted while in the foreground by a phone call is different than being in the background. In the latter case, you're not the foreground app to begin with, so it could be this is a special case, or an edge case, or a bug. If you believe it's a bug in the SDK, you should report it to Apple.

Comment: To be 100% clear.  When the phone call comes in, even if in background, we get the Start and End events and then do a Local Notification.  No End Event, no Local Notification.

Comment: Seems to be about the same with iTunes.  Sometimes I get the End event  at the Start of the Video (or just after it starts), but not always.  Yes, this looks like some sort of problem with the SDK / IOS right now.  Will have to log with Apple.

Comment: Ok, I get it. So, with your app in the background, launch the iTunes app and play a song. Does your app get an End event when you stop the iTunes app? Just trying to get some other data points here... I am thinking that "getting a phone call" is a little different, somehow, than "anything else that uses audio", when it comes to the interruption notifications. Don't know for sure, but it sure seems that way.

Comment: After much testing, this has been logged as a bug with Apple.  10818245

Comment: @ort11 I am having this issue to, have you found a way around this?

Comment: Same problem here. Thank you for filing the bug. Is there any progress in fixing it? Unfortunately, we cannot see the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, about the time of the posting, I Logged a bug report with Apple with a small app the demonstrated the issue.  So far have heard nothing.....  So the answer is there still is no answer....